# Simple Idea in Vectors isn't working (Compilation errors)

Tags: c++, memory, vector, compiler-errors

What is wrong with this code

```
vector< vector<int> > elements(lvls+1);

for(int p=1;p<=lvls;p++)
    elements[p] = new vector<int>(p+1,0);
```

or

```
vector< vector<int> > elements(lvls+1);

for(int p=1;p<=lvls;p++)
    elements[p] ( vector<int>(p+1,0) );
```

Both of them aren't working

While we know

```
vector< vector<int> > elements(lvls+1,vector<int>(lvls+1,0));
```

this works..

I can do this but it is not optimal as it will lead to waste of memory 
Kindly provide the solution

Comment: In your first case elements contain vector of int but you are asigning the pointer.  In your second case elements[p] you are accessing pth element which is a vector itself  and no call operator is defined for vector.

Comment: define not working. Doesnt compile? Doesnt run?

Comment: For the second one, you are attempting to invoke the vector elements as functions. Since `int` does not define a call operator it doesn't work, clang error msg `error: type 'value_type' (aka 'std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >') does not provide a call operator`. The way to fix it is to take the first one and remove the new.

Comment: can u write the code ? @PaulRooney

Answer (score 2):

You should write it that way:

```
vector< vector<int> > elements(lvls+1);

for(int p=0; p < lvls + 1; p++)
    elements[p].resize(p+1, 0);`
```

Each vector element in vector called `elements` is already initialized, not need to use `new` or constructor. I guess you only wanted to `resize` it, so here you are.

Comment: Thank you very much .. Working now . I will remember your advice

Comment: No problem,, yw :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your first attempt is that you are trying to assign a pointer to a vector of `int` i.e., `vector<int>*` to a `vector<int>` (not a pointer). You could simply remove the `new` keyword, like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> elements(lvls + 1);
for (int p = 1; p <= lvls; p++)
    elements[p] = std::vector<int>(p + 1, 0);
```

This will invoke the [move assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D): `operator=(vector&&)`

**Off-topic**

Is there any reason why you are not using the first element (index `0`)  in `elements`?

Comment: yep i take my numbering/indexing from 1